# How to 'A RenderFlex overflowed by 61 pixels on the bottom.' on the top of the virtual Keyboard for android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

this is the UI. and below is the main.dart file and error message
[image: this is UI for the error]
I am using Text Field in my Flutter app which gives the render flex error at the top the virtual keyboard. Please check the below code.
at the bottom i have added the error message.
and previously i tried every other ways to solve the issue but i condn't

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './transaction.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Expenses Tracker',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Transaction> transactions = [
    Transaction(
      id: 't1',
      title: 'New Shoes',
      amount: 87.25,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
    Transaction(
      id: 't2',
      title: 'Weekly Groceries',
      amount: 83.25,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Expenses Tracker'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Card(
              child: Text("Chart!"),
              color: Colors.deepOrange,
              elevation: 9,
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            elevation: 5,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Amount'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: transactions.map((tx) {
              return Card(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 10,
                        horizontal: 15,
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.purple,
                          width: 3,
                        ),
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Text(
                        '\$ ${tx.amount}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.purple,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          tx.title,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 18,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          DateFormat.yMMMEd().format(tx.date),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 14),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

below is the error .

```
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 61 pixels on the bottom.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Column 
lib\main.dart:41
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,
like a ListView.
The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#0559b relayoutBoundary=up1 OVERFLOWING:
  needs compositing
  creator: Column ← _BodyBuilder ← MediaQuery ← LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ←
    CustomMultiChildLayout ← AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ←
    _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#39d3c ink renderer] ← NotificationListener<LayoutChangedNotification> ←
    PhysicalModel ← AnimatedPhysicalModel ← ⋯
  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 80.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=360.0, 0.0<=h<=263.0)
  size: Size(360.0, 263.0)
  direction: vertical
mainAxisAlignment: start
  mainAxisSize: max
  crossAxisAlignment: center
  verticalDirection: down

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: What is not clear about this error

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. A quick solution would be to block the widgets inside the `Scaffold` to resize themselves when the keyboard opens but this way,

> **some widgets can be `obscured` by the keyboard**

We can do this using the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` property on the `Scaffold` widget.

Example:

```
 return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,   //new line
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Expenses Tracker'),
      ),
      body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ...... // other widgets 
          ],
      ),
    );
```

---

2. Another solution is to wrap the `Column` widget into a scrollable widget. A built-in widget provided by `Flutter` which works well is the `SingleChildScrollView`. This is the best solution to avoid the `“Bottom overflowed”` error when the keyboard opens.

```
 return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Expenses Tracker'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView( // wrap with a scrollable widget
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ...... // other widgets 
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 4):

Try setting `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,` in your `Scaffold`

Like this.

```
Scaffold(
 resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
 ...
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use SingleChildScrollView  . It means
A box in which a single widget can be scrolled.
so first go to colums ctrls+Shift+R you can get wrapwith widget and click it and add SingleChildScrollView

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Expenses Tracker'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(child:Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Card(
              child: Text("Chart!"),
              color: Colors.deepOrange,
              elevation: 9,
            ),
          ),).
```